# Powershell Send-MailMessage only sending e-mail to the last recipient

Tags: powershell, sendmail

I have this script in powershell to send an e-mail using a external file :

```
powershell.exe -command " & {$content = Get-Content -Path    "%dirtemp%\%arquivomail%"  | Out-String ;  
$users= get-content -Path %dir%\%arquivocc% | Out-String ;
Send-MailMessage -SMTPServer 10.7.16.5 
-To $users
- cc %cc% 
-From 'mymail' 
-Subject '%assunto%' 
-Body $content 
-BodyAsHtml -Encoding UTF8}"
```

My $users is a txt file with 2 e-mails like this:

```
aaaa@mail.com, bbbb@mail.com
```

The thing ins that when I run the script in my Batch file, the e-mail is only sent to bbbb@mail.com, the last e-mail.

I need to send them to all the e-mails in the text file. 
Any Ideas?

Comment: I think your `To` needs to be an array. You have it convertting to a string. Could trying just saving the users in the variable and then just referencing it when using `Send-MailMessage`. Looks like you are running a `BAT File`. Have you tried via PowerShell directly for testing?

Comment: Easiest fix is to put each email on its own line in the text file (no commas or spaces) then remove Out-String. This will mean Get-Content produces the array you need for you: `$users= Get-Content -Path %dir%\%arquivocc%`